# Dynamically import WebAssembly from variable

Tags: javascript, import, webassembly, deno, dynamic-import

It's possible to dynamically import Javascript from a string:

```js
const code = "console.log('Hello, world!');"

import("data:text/javascript;base64," + btoa(code));
```

I have a `Uint8Array` containing code compiled to WebAssembly, and I want to dynamically import it in the same way:

```js
import("data:binary/webassembly;base64,..."); // Something like this
```

Comment: What do you mean by _import_? WASM modules are used by instantiating them and then calling their exports. If that's what you want to do, then `WebAssembly.instantiate(bufferSource, importObject)` seems like the way to go. `bufferSource` can be a "typed array" like the `Uint8Array` you already have.

Comment: Oh, I didn't tag `deno`! In Deno you can import WASM from files.

Comment: Hm, obviously I'm missing something. By design (e.g. sandboxing reasons), JS and WASM code lives in isolated domains. One can't do a "blanket" _import_ of a wasm module into JS space. Instead, you get individual WASM functions via a module's instance exports. The first google hit for "deno wasm" seems to demonstrate exactly that (https://deno.land/manual@v1.8.3/getting_started/webassembly). But I'm sure you've already seen that, so you are probably asking about something else. :-)

Comment: No you're right, I was asking if it's possible to use an import statement so that I could treat JS and WASM modules identically, but now I see why that doesn't work. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import WebAssembly code in your imported JavaScript/TypeScript code.

The following uses the example from Using [WebAssembly in Deno | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual@v1.25.3/webassembly/using_wasm):

```
const code = `\
const wasmCode = new Uint8Array([
  0, 97, 115, 109, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 133, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 96, 0, 1, 127,
  3, 130, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 0, 4, 132, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 112, 0, 0,
  5, 131, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 0, 1, 6, 129, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0, 7, 145,
  128, 128, 128, 0, 2, 6, 109, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 2, 0, 4, 109, 97,
  105, 110, 0, 0, 10, 138, 128, 128, 128, 0, 1, 132, 128, 128, 128, 0, 0,
  65, 42, 11
]);

const wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmCode);

const wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule);

const main = wasmInstance.exports.main as CallableFunction;
console.log(main().toString());
`;

import("data:text/typescript;base64," + btoa(code));
```

The same can be done using `text/javascript` rather than `text/typescript` as long as you remove the type cast in the code.